# Center floating divs in container

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a website without using framework however I have run into a problem. My divs are not getting centered within the container even though the container itself is centered in the body.

Html

```
<body>
<div id="content">
 <div class="box">

 </div>
 <div class="box">

 </div>
 <div class="box">

 </div>
 <div class="box">

 </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#content{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 13px;
}
```

The divs are perfectly centered when I have my window to full width, but once I resize it, they just reorganize without centering.

Before resizing:
http://cl.ly/image/241R2I24280w/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-26%20at%2021.49.23.png
After resizing the window: http://cl.ly/image/2y2g2W0n230g/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-26%20at%2021.50.21.png

I have tried different methods to solve it, such as doing `margin: 0 -10%;` and `margin: 0 25%;`
When it comes to positioning I get confused.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your CSS like this, this way you can adapt your boxes in many ways and they will react to responsive layouts as expected:

```
#content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.box {
    width: 45%;
    height: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 13px 2%;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3gb7jt3/)

**Explanation:**

I have removed your floats, used block elements and replaced your fixed sizes by percentages. Then, I used a `text-align:center` property in your container box `#content` so everything is nicely aligned in the center of that container. Now, if you resize, columns will take 45% of the width of the screen, but you can obviously change the behavior via media queries and use something like `.box{display:box}` for small screens

Comment: Hello, it was almost perfect :) I edited it a bit to keep the original width (I don't want the boxes to become smaller). I appreciate the fiddle example too!
`.box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 12px 1%;
}`

Comment: wait, in that case, keep the width at 45%, just add `min-width:400px`

Comment: Oh okay thanks! on a further note, I really appreciate the explanation too, helps me since I'm not the best at positioning.

Comment: glad you appreciate it, many people thinks it's just "give me free code" instead of learning how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. Depending on what you have inside those boxes this might be the simplest one: `text-align:center`with a `display:inline-block` combo; See here.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pooyodz9/2/)

Comment: I was thinking of filling them with an image and overlay it with a headline

Comment: Go ahead and try. If it doesn't work off the bat add in the commented css from the fiddle. If that does not work, explore additional options.

Comment: Thanks I tried your fiddle and it worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions :
You can use  a percentage for the width your `boxes`.

```
#content{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10%;
}

.box{
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 13px;
}
```

Boxes will resize with the content but the stuff in the boxes might look weird in small sizes.

Or
You can use a pixel value for the width of your `content`.

```
#content{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10%;
}

.box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 13px;
}
```

Width of boxes will not change while resizing, nor the stuff in it, but that can be painful on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

add auto margin for your box

```
.box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made your files on my machine and the divs are not centered so I assume your screen or resolution settings are different, or your content container is within one or more other divs?

Anyhow, try adding 'clear:left;' in your box class code and it should resolve your issue (put it just above the 'float:left' line. good luck!